# Sql Query Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have added a Execute Sql Task in my Project.I have added a Sql query in it

```
Insert into M1
select * from M4
```

But the problem is M1 table is in AAA database & M4 table is in DDD Database.

It is showing some error...?

Comment: What is the error? Are both databases on the same server or not? What version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: Error-Cannot parse this query.Both the database are on same server.Server is my local machine & i have Sql server 2008 installed in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both databases are on the same server then fully qualify the table names:

```
insert into AAA.dbo.M1 (col1, col2, ...)
select col1, col2, ...
from DDD.dbo.M4
```

Of course, if your objects are not in the dbo schema then you need to put the correct one. You should never use `SELECT *` by the way, it can lead to problems if you ever change the table structure (or someone else does). Instead, always specify the column names.

An alternative would be to use a data flow to copy the data, but that's probably unnecessary here.

Comment: ya,i got the problem that i was not putting the Database name in Sql query.Thanks for helping me out..!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Data Flow Task. add a OLE DB Source and a OLE DB Destination. Then configure source and destination as required. 
[Take a look at here](http://www.sql-server-business-intelligence.com/sql-server/ssis/create-ssis-package-find-an-example-how-to-create-an-ssis-package-a-simple-one)

Comment: ya,i know that this work can be done through Data flow task.but i don't want to draw relations in ssis.I want this work to be done Execute Sql Task in SSIS.