# Data to be inserted by SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a table known as Customer(DATABASE AAA) containing 3 fields

```
Cust_id Cust_name Cust_salary
1         A        2000
2         B        3000
3         C         NULL
```

I want to put data of these 3 columns in Employee(DATABASE BBB) which has the same structure as of Customer.

I want to transfer records of only those customer in which Cust_salary part is not null.

This work is to be done in SSIS only. MY values for Cust_id is auto generated & before putting values to Employee_id,the Employee table should be deleted.The auto generated identity should be preserved.

Comment: This is just a [Data Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) Task, with an OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination. The query for the source is `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Cust_Salary IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You may remember my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799358/sql-query-task-in-ssis Also, please try to understand the difference between SQL and SSIS; you are asking a lot of questions about SSIS but in almost every case so far the real question is about SQL, not about SSIS. This is another such case.

Comment: @manoj: You **really** should start learning SQL!

Comment: I can do that work by writing Simple query in sql server 2008.But i want to do this work in ssis only

Comment: Look at the answer I provided.  You can accomplish this via SSIS.

Comment: what did you try? I gave the guidelines on my answer, you just need to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darren Davies answer seems correct, but if for some obscure reason you have an EmployeeID is also an identity column and needs to match Cust_ID, and assuming any entries already in the Employee table correspond with the correct customer you can use an Execute SQL Task in SSIS with a connection open to Database BBB to run the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary)
SELECT  Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Cust_Salary
FROM    AAA..Customer
WHERE   Cust_Salary IS NOT NULL
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Employee
            WHERE   EmployeeID = Cust_ID
        )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee OFF
```

This will maintain the integrity of the Identity fields in each table, and only insert new Customers to the Employee table.

Comment: Can the above work can be done without SQL Execute Task in SSIS

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be done in SSIS? Is EmployeeID an Identity column?

Comment: Its a complicate to explain you why i need this work to be done in SSIS.ya,Employee_ID is an identity column.

Comment: The answer you have accepted, and the solution I indicated in my comment to your answer is the way to achieve this without Execute SQL task. Use a data flow, with OLE DB Source (Choosing SQL command as the access mode with the query I have given above as the command text (SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name...)), and an OLE DB Destination (Choosing Employee as the destination table). You then have various options, one of which is "Keep Identity". Ensure this is checked and that the source and destination are linked with the green arrow. Then run the package.

Comment: Thanks GarethD for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You could create a SQL Execute Task in SSIS and run the following:

```
INSERT INTO Employee
 (EmployeeId, EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary)
 SELECT Cust_id, Cust_name, Cust_salary
 FROM Customer
 WHERE Cust_salary IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This would not work, you would need to wrap the fields to insert to in brackets i.e. (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary), and fully qualify the database name of at least one of the tables (AAA..Customer or BBB..Employee), this is assuming they are on the same server ofcourse.

Comment: This would work in SSIS by creating a SQL Execute Task object as stated in my post.  Gareth, I spotted that before you commented and changed already. Thanks

Comment: MY values for Cust_id is auto generated & before putting values to Employee_id,the Employee table should be deleted.The auto generated identity should be preserved.

Comment: You want to DROP the Employee table or delete the rows from it? There's a difference.  You could do DELETE FROM Employee before the INSERT I provided,  the auto generated ID will be preserved in Customer and Employee as long as Employee ID does not have an IDENTITY column on it.

Comment: Can the above work can be done without SQL Execute Task in SSIS

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing it an alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

what have you tried?

You will need two connections, one for each DB and one data flow component which will have a OleDBSource and an OleDBDestination component inside.

On the OleDBSource you can select your connection and write your query and then you drag the green arrow to the OleDBDestination. Double click the OleDBDestination select destination connection and table and click on mapping.

Should be it

Comment: Can the above work can be done without SQL Execute Task in SSIS

Comment: I don't need SQl Execute Task